# Why is it not portable to use the extension .hpp for C++-header files?

Tags: c++, r, filenames

The [Writing R Extensions manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) explains that: "Using .hpp is not guaranteed to be portable." (Footnote 18 in Section 1.1.5)

I would like to know: What does this sentence mean?  What might go wrong if a C++-header file has the wrong extension?

I am not sure whether this remark only refers to the context of writing R extensions or whether this remark is valid more generally.

Comment: [C++ FAQ: What header-file-name convention is best? foo.H? foo.hh? foo.hpp?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#hdr-file-ext). There is no specific requirement of any specific suffix. Standard C++ headers even don't have any suffix. Using specific conventions helps for maintenance (e.g. to filter for certain files in build tools).

Comment: Thanks for the link. https://isocpp.org sounds like a good authority on this issue.

Comment: @jarauh: Correct, but Boost is also at the same level of authority. Both groups have a large overlap with the people who actually define C++ (ISO's programming language Working Group 21 aka WG21).

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I agree. Both are good sources and more authoritative than other blog or forum entries (which mostly point into the same direction).

Answer (score 1):

It *is* portable from a C++ standards perspective. Boost use `hpp` and they are always worth following. (I use `hpp` too, in order to distinguish any C language headers.)

(Some folk even use `tpp` for template files. I don't, principally because it would mess up my antiquated build system and I don't see the point of attempting to make a distinction - some headers contain a blend of template and non-template code.)

It's just that the R community don't *think* they are portable. In other words, it does refer to the context of writing R extensions.

Comment: Thanks. However, I would not say it is the general "R community", but rather the R Core Team.